Spring MVC Project missing
Since 2022, I have not used Eclipse, and now I want to create a “Spring Legacy Project”. I entered the Eclipse Marketplace, and because “Spring Tool 3 (Standalone Edition) 3.9.14. RELEASE” is no longer maintained, I had to download the “Spring Tools 3 Add-On For Spring Tools 4 3.9.22. RELEASE”. I also downloaded Spring Tool 4, but it didn't serve my intended purpose. The problem is that the Add-On for Spring Tool 4 does not come with all the templates, which it used to have about 3 years ago. By this, I mean when you select "Spring Legacy Project" and within the "Persistence" template, you find a template project called "Spring MVC Project". Currently, it no longer includes the "Persistence" template (nor templates like Batch, GemFire, Integration), so I don't have the option to choose "Spring MVC Project" either. I have Eclipse Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0). It seems that the problem is that Spring Tool Suite SPT 3 is already outdated and the ADD-ON plugin is also outdated and when downloading SPT 4, Spring Legacy Project does not appear, because it focuses on Springboot. What can I do to get the "Persistence" template and the subsequent "Spring MVC Project" option?
I tried to install both STS 3, the add-on for STS 4, and STS 4, and it always appeared an error when they were being integrated during the installation. In addition, there are some items that are not installed such as “Spring IDE Core” that are required, that can't be installed. The AI ​​suggests that I create a Maven project and then select an archetype like maven-archetype-webapp, and then make all the configurations in the pom.xml, in the web.xml, in the dispatcher-servlet.xml, but I have The impression that this answer confuses me. I need to know if it is currently possible to install that persistence template, which includes the Spring MVC Project file.

No it isn't as you already discovered that is deprecated now and people or encouraged to use Spring Boot. If that isn't what you want write your own pom.xml.
